# TypeScript type guard with a throwable

Tags: typescript

Consider this simplified class definition:

```
class Lockfile {
    private StaleLock = Error

    public lockPath: string
    public lock: fs.promises.FileHandle | null

    constructor(lockPath: string) {
        this.lockPath = lockPath
        this.lock = null
    }

    public async write(data: string) {
        if (this.lock === null) {
            throw this.StaleLock(`Not holding lock on file: ${this.lockPath}`)
        }
        await this.lock.write(data)
    }

    public async commit() {
        if (this.lock === null) {
            throw this.StaleLock(`Not holding lock on file: ${this.lockPath}`)
        }
        await this.lock.close()
    }
}
```

The `lock` property is guarded in both `write` and `commit` but the conditional.

I want to move the guard logic into its own function like so:

```
class Lockfile {
    private StaleLock = Error

    public lockPath: string
    public lock: fs.promises.FileHandle | null

    constructor(lockPath: string) {
        this.lockPath = lockPath
        this.lock = null
    }

    public async write(data: string) {
        this.throwOnStaleLock()
        await this.lock?.write(data)
    }

    public async commit() {
        this.throwOnStaleLock()
        await this.lock?.close()
    }

    public throwOnStaleLock() {
        if (this.lock === null) {
            throw this.StaleLock(`Not holding lock on file: ${this.lockPath}`)
        }
    }
}
```

But now, the `write` and `commit` functions lose their type guards. Is there something I need to add to the `throwOnStaleLock` method? Or is this a bad pattern?

For context, this is a conversion of some Ruby code that doesn't have to deal with type safety principles so maybe there is a better way to structure the code too!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a type assertion for that, if you have a recent enough (>= 3.7) version of *TypeScript*:

```js
public throwOnStaleLock(lock: fs.promises.FileHandle | null): assert lock is fs.promises.FileHandle {
  if (lock === null) {
    throw this.StaleLock(`Not holding lock on file: ${this.lockPath}`)
  }
}
```

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this, but this is inside a class so I'm trying to refrain from passing a property to a function when it can already access it from the `this` context. This may also be an indicator the code could be better organized in some other way; object-oriented isn't always my favorite approach